# Computing the commutator of the Fock and density matrices in AO basis (Hartree-Fock theory)

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I am making a simple restricted HF code using the Python interface of Psi4. I am now evaluating convergence by tracking the change in the sum of orbital energies, but I want to do this in a better way. It is common to use the fact that at self-consistency, the Fock and density matrices commute

$$
[\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{D}] = \mathbf{FD} - \mathbf{DF} = \mathbf{0}
$$

However, the above expression is only valid in MO basis, while F and D in my code are computed in AO basis. So I need to derive an equivalent expression in AO basis. I am quite sure the correct expression is

$$
[\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{D}]^{\text{AO}} = \mathbf{FDS} - \mathbf{SDF}
$$

as this is equal to zero to within $1\times10^{-14}$. But how to derive this?

### Derivation

An arbitrary molecular orbital $\phi_i$ is expanded in atomic orbital basis functions

$$
\phi_i = \sum_\alpha C_{\alpha i} \chi _{\alpha}
$$

Acting the commutator on $\phi_i$ and expanding it to AO basis yields

$$
[\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{D}] = \mathbf{FD} \sum_\alpha C_{\alpha i} \chi_{\alpha}  - \mathbf{DF} \sum_\alpha C_{\alpha i} \chi_{\alpha}
$$

Since we know the solution contains the overlap matrix $\mathbf{S}$, lets look at the definition

$$
\mathbf{S}_{ij} = \langle \chi_i(\mathbf{r}) \vert \chi_j(\mathbf{r}) \rangle = \int d\mathbf{r} \chi^*(\mathbf{r})\chi(\mathbf{r})
$$

Since this must be part of our expression, it seems to me a good approach is to multiply from the left by $\sum_\beta C_{\beta i}^* \chi_\beta^*$ (dropping the $\mathbf{r}$ dependence from now on) and integrating over $\mathbf{r}$

$$
[\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{D}] = \int \sum_\beta C_{\beta i}^* \chi_\beta^* \mathbf{FD} \sum_\alpha C_{\alpha i} \chi_{\alpha}  - \int \sum_\beta C_{\beta i}^* \chi_\beta^* \mathbf{DF} \sum_\alpha C_{\alpha i} \chi_{\alpha}
$$

from in braket notation becomes

$$
[\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{D}] = \langle \sum_\beta C_{\beta i} \chi_\beta \vert \mathbf{FD} \vert \sum_\alpha C_{\alpha i} \chi_{\alpha} \rangle  - \langle \sum_\beta C_{\beta i} \chi_\beta \vert \mathbf{DF} \vert \sum_\alpha C_{\alpha i} \chi_{\alpha} \rangle
$$

At this point I am not sure what to do - or if am I even on the right track. I can see that we have the "pieces" that make up the overlap matrix, but I don't know how to put them together. Further, due to the orthonormality of the MOs, then I can imagine that the summation terms only survive when $\alpha = \beta$. But I'm not sure how to derive this properly.

Comment: Slightly related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102144/is-the-lowdin-orthogonalization-used-in-diagonalizing-the-atomic-orbitals-really

Comment: In the context of a DIIS error function, Jensen (2nd ed., ISBN 1118825993) references your AO expression. He gives the following references: https://doi.org/10.1002/jcc.540030413 https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1470195

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start from the AO Hartree-Fock equation and its adjoint 
$$\mathbf{F}^{AO}\mathbf{T}=\mathbf{S}\mathbf{T}\epsilon \text{ and } \mathbf{T^\dagger}\mathbf{F}^{AO}=\epsilon\mathbf{T^\dagger}\mathbf{S}$$

where $\mathbf{T}$ is an $N\times n$ matrix that is essentially the occupied block of $\mathbf{C}$ ($n$ is occupied, $N$ is total orbitals). We use this $\mathbf{T}$ matrix because it has the convenient property that

$$\mathbf{T}\mathbf{T}^\dagger=\mathbf{D}^{AO}$$

Now, we can multiply the HF equation by $\mathbf{T^\dagger}\mathbf{S}$ on the right and multiply its adjoint by $\mathbf{S}\mathbf{T}$ on the left, which gives

$$\mathbf{F}^{AO}\mathbf{T}\mathbf{T^\dagger}\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{S}\mathbf{T}\epsilon\mathbf{T^\dagger}\mathbf{S}$$

$$\mathbf{S}\mathbf{T}\mathbf{T^\dagger}\mathbf{F}^{AO}=\mathbf{S}\mathbf{T}\epsilon\mathbf{T^\dagger}\mathbf{S}$$

Subtracting the first equation from the second and yields the desired commutator relationship.

$$\mathbf{F}^{AO}\mathbf{D}^{AO}\mathbf{S}-\mathbf{S}\mathbf{D}^{AO}\mathbf{F}^{AO}=\mathbf{0}$$

The notation I use here is based on a similar derivation given in Chapter 6 of McWeeny's Methods of Molecular Quantum Mechanics, 2nd edition.

Comment: If $\mathbf{B}$ is the "normal" coefficient matrix in the Roothan-Hall matrix equation, then the density matrix we use in our calculations is $\mathbf{C}\mathbf{C}^{\dagger}$Is $\mathbf{T}$ only over the occupied molecular orbitals. Is this what is referred to as the "reduced density matrix"? The $\mathbf{T}$ matrix in your answer is not what we get when we diagonalize the fock matrix, right?

Comment: The density is just built from the occupied MO coefficients (see this [tutorial](http://sirius.chem.vt.edu/wiki/doku.php?id=crawdad:programming:project3)). While you can solve the HF equation with C instead of T, the Fock matrix itself only depends on the occupied orbitals.

Comment: Related discussion on density matrices: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/80351/41556

Answer (score 5):

Starting from statement that the Fock matrix and the density matrix commute in an orthonormal basis.
$$
[\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{D}] = \mathbf{FD} - \mathbf{DF} = \mathbf{0}
$$
The orthonormal basis matrices can be substituted for their equivalents in an atomic orbital basis
\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} = {} & \mathbf{X}^\dagger \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{X} \\
\implies \mathbf{F}^{AO} = {} & \left[\mathbf{X}^\dagger\right]^{-1} \mathbf{F} \mathbf{X}^{-1}\\
\mathbf{D}^{AO} = {} & \mathbf{X} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{X}^\dagger \\
\implies \mathbf{D} = {} &  \mathbf{X}^{-1} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \left[\mathbf{X}^\dagger\right]^{-1} 
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{X}$ is an orthogonalisation matrix.  :
\begin{align}
[\mathbf{F}, \mathbf{D}] = {} & \mathbf{FD} - \mathbf{DF} = \mathbf{0} \\
= {} & \mathbf{X}^\dagger \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{X}
\mathbf{X}^{-1} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \left[\mathbf{X}^\dagger\right]^{-1}
- \mathbf{X}^{-1} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \left[\mathbf{X}^\dagger\right]^{-1} 
\mathbf{X}^\dagger \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{X} \\
= {} & \mathbf{X}^\dagger \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \left[\mathbf{X}^\dagger\right]^{-1}
- \mathbf{X}^{-1} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{X}
\end{align}

When $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{S}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, pre and postmultiplying by $\mathbf{X}^{-1} = \mathbf{S}^{\frac{1}{2}}$:

\begin{align}
\mathbf{X}^{-1} \mathbf{0} \mathbf{X}^{-1} = {} &
\mathbf{X}^{-1} \mathbf{X}^\dagger \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \left[\mathbf{X}^\dagger\right]^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{-1}
- \mathbf{X}^{-1}
\mathbf{X}^{-1} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{X}
\mathbf{X}^{-1} \\
\mathbf{0} = {} & \mathbf{F}^{AO} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \mathbf{S} - \mathbf{S} \mathbf{D}^{AO} \mathbf{F}^{AO}
\end{align}

as you have suggested.

Comment: While your derivation makes sense, the choice of $X = S^{-1/2}$ is not the only possible orthogonalization, and I think that the final equation does not depend on the choice.

Comment: The transformation of the Fock matrix into an orthonormal AO basis is fine. But it is not clear to me why a very similar transformation of the density matrix changes the basis from MO to AO (and vice versa), and not just between AO and orthogonalized AO basis.

Comment: Just noticed that you specifically asked about the MO basis rather any general orthogonalised basis.  Hence why I started in the orthogonal AO basis.  Will update to explain connection to MO basis shortly

Comment: @user213305 Did you update your answer?